# I keep getting a "vector subscript out of range" error and I can't figure out why

Tags: c++, 2d-vector

I have an assignment where I have to read from a text file two matrices and two integers indicating the number of rows and columns they each have, add them together, then write them to a new text file. I have to do this by overloading both the + and << operators, as that's what we went over in class before this was assigned. I don't know if it's the get or set method I wrote for the values of the 2d vector, but no matter what I try I always get the "vector subscript out of range" error.

Input file:
3   5

1   2   3   4   5
10  8   6   4   2
-5  5   -1  1   0

9   7   5   3   1
11  11  11  11  11
6   5   6   5   6

Matrix.h:

```
#define MATRIX_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Matrix {
public:
    //constructor
    Matrix(unsigned int initial_rows = 0, unsigned int initial_columns = 0) :
        num_of_rows(initial_rows), num_of_columns(initial_columns) {
        if (num_of_rows * num_of_columns > 0)
        {
            data.resize(num_of_rows, std::vector<int>(num_of_columns));
        }
    }
    
    //operators
    Matrix operator + (const Matrix&) const;
    friend std::ostream& operator << (const std::ostream&, const Matrix&);

    //getters
    unsigned int get_num_of_rows() const;
    unsigned int get_num_of_columns() const;

    //class member functions
    int get(unsigned int i, unsigned int j) const;
    void set(unsigned int i, unsigned int j, int val);

private:
    //data fields
    unsigned int num_of_rows;
    unsigned int num_of_columns;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;
};
#endif
```

Class Source:

```
//getters
unsigned int Matrix::get_num_of_rows() const { return num_of_rows; }
unsigned int Matrix::get_num_of_columns() const { return num_of_columns; }

/** returns value stored at row index i and column index j
*   @param i: row index i
*   @param j: column index j
*   @returns: value at row index i and column index j
*/
int Matrix::get(unsigned int i, unsigned int j) const {
    return data[i][j];
}

/** assigns val with the integer found at data[i][j]
*   @param i: row index i
*   @param j: column index j
*   @param val: integer found at [i][j]
*/
void Matrix::set(unsigned int i, unsigned int j, int val) {
    for (i = 0; i < num_of_rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < num_of_columns; j++) {
            val = data[i][j];
        }
    }
}

/** Overloads addition operator for "Matrix + Matrix"
*   @param other: second operand
*   @returns: sum of two matrices
*/
Matrix Matrix::operator + (const Matrix& other) const {
    Matrix result;
    if (num_of_rows == other.num_of_rows && num_of_columns == other.num_of_columns) {
        result.data[num_of_rows][num_of_columns] = data[num_of_rows][num_of_columns] + other.data[num_of_rows][num_of_columns];
    }
    return result;
}

/** Overloads insertion operator for "Matrix
*   @param: istream
*   @param: Matrix object
*/
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream out, const Matrix& matrix) {
    return out << matrix.get_num_of_rows() << matrix.get_num_of_columns() << std::endl;
    for (unsigned int i; i < matrix.get_num_of_rows(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int j; j < matrix.get_num_of_columns(); i++) {
            return out << matrix.get(i, j);
        }
        out << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    //open input file
    std::ifstream fin("matrices_1.txt");
    if (!fin) {
        std::cout << "Input file not found" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //open output file
    std::ofstream fout("result.txt");

    //declare variables
    Matrix matrix1;
    Matrix matrix2;
    unsigned int numRows;
    unsigned int numColumns;
    int value;

    //read number of rows and columns
    fin >> numRows >> numColumns;
    std::string line;
    getline(fin, line);
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> data(numRows, std::vector<unsigned int>(numColumns));

    //read dimenstions of first matrix
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            fin >> value;
            matrix1.set(i, j, value);
            std::cout << matrix1.get(i, j);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    
    //read dimensions of second matrix
    getline(fin, line);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            fin >> value;
            //matrix2.set(i, j, value);
        }
    }

    //add matrices
    Matrix result = matrix1 + matrix2;

    //print result to output file
    fout << result;

    //close input and output files
    fin.close();
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Attach your debugger and it will break execution at the moment the exception is thrown. You can then look back in the stack to see exactly which line of code invoked it, and what values contributed to the program state at that time.

Comment: Oh, well, also a quick skim over your code shows that `operator+` is accessing every vector out-of-bounds. If you're trying to element-wise add the matrices you need a loop. The way you wrote it is attempting to access an element down and to the right of the bottom-most right-most element. Oftentimes, mistakes like this just indicate you need to take a break and/or have a sleep. You are looping in other places in the code, so it's not like it's a new idea.

Comment: **Additional Problem**: Remove the `const` from the first parameter in the declaration `friend std::ostream& operator << (const std::ostream&, const Matrix&);`. The first parameter when overloading `operator<<` should not have a `const`. Also, can you add a sample input text file in your question.

Comment: There, I added the input file to the question. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Ok, so I ran the debugger and it throws the exception as soon as soon as the return value in the get function is invoked because it's being initialized with size 0 for some reason. So I guess my question now is how do I actually initialize it with the size needed?